# Custom dropdown list field type in datasheet view (MOSS)

Tags: custom-field-types, datasheet

I would like to create a custom field type that renders a dropdown list, specifically to be used in the datasheet view. In the datasheet view it should render a dropdown list, (like a lookup field of choice field). The dropdown list items should be created at runtime through some server logic.

Is it possible? (MOSS 2007)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default it is not supported. If you create a custom field type and a an instance to a list your will see a warning. Due to custome code that can be involved it is pretty hard to get this field and code inside of the client applications. The datagrid view is a part of the office components and therefor a "client" application (ActiveX)

Maybe you can check out this blog post for a workaround and see if your field will be able to fit in this solution:

http://nickgrattan.wordpress.com/2008/01/06/sharepoint-2007-custom-fields-and-edit-property-on-server/

Ciao Marco