# Understanding Data Sheet view list better in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list, datasheet

I would like to know more about the features of Data sheet type lists.

1. Can I use conditional modification to the data sheet rows, for
   example changing the color if a column value equal 'X' ?
2. Can I use cascading effect in Data
   sheet view, for example based on Country would like to get city field...
3. Can I change the default height of the data sheet view. If yes
   how?
4. Can I view the datasheet in full screen ?
5. Can I show long column headings in two lines?
6. Can I permanently make the data sheet list to sort based on a particular
   column? Explanation - If I open the Data sheet type list - by
   default I would like to get the data sheet sorted on particular
   field?

Comment: Next time I'd recommend breaking these down into separate questions; it's better to have one correct markable answer than several answers that deal with different parts. Luckily there's one brief answer for all these questions. :)

Comment: Will Take care of that in future Stuart :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. No
2. No
3. No
4. No
5. No
6. <strike>No</strike> Yes, apparently:

> Create a view and select a Sort By column, then set that view as the
>   default view

The DataSheet view does not play ball. The problem is that the DataSheet view is a Microsoft Access generated data table, so there are none of the usual SharePoint hooks for interacting with it.

Here are some more related questions:

> Q: Can I use JavaScript in the DataSheet view?
>   [Can I use JavaScript in 'Edit in DataSheet' mode?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16830/can-i-use-javascript-in-edit-in-datasheet-mode)

A: No.

> Q: Can I use a CEWP with a DataSheet view?
>   [Customising Data Sheet View](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16732/customising-data-sheet-view)

A: No.

> Q: Can I add a Custom Control to a DataSheet View?
>   [How do I create custom control or action that works in a list's DataSheet view?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16612/how-do-i-create-custom-control-or-action-that-works-in-a-lists-datasheet-view)

A: No.

> Q: Can I have custom drop-down list values in the DataSheet View?
>   [Custom dropdown list field type in datasheet view (MOSS)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3854/custom-dropdown-list-field-type-in-datasheet-view-moss)

A: No.

> Q: Can I-

A: No.

*Edit: This post inspired me to write an article on some of the most common datasheet questions and answers: [Pentalogic Blog: SharePoint Datasheet FAQ](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2012/10/sharepoint-datasheet-faq/)*

Comment: SO non of my requirements can be done :) Very bad :) Thanks for spending time on this !!

Comment: Question 6 Indeed I got it worked, created a view and selected required sort field and set that view as a default view. :)

Comment: @Jithu: :O Good call! I'll update my answer accordingly. It seems I got a bit carried away with my "No"s. :)

Comment: That's fine :) At least we got one yes :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a REPORT-VIEW in MS-ACCESS, and that will affect the SharePoint-DataSheet-View, once you 'link' it properly.   This requires that specific MS-ACCESS database to either be present on every machine (client-side) that will use this view, or be present on the server and accessed as on OLE or something similar to the Excel-Services connections.  Idunno exactly, but that is what I gathered so far.

This is incredibly bush-league, especially since Data-Sheet-View allows you to modify Fonts that are in Multi-Line-Fields and/or Rich-Text-Fields.  I cannot even begin to fathom why the (expletive) they did not also allow single-line text fields, and at the very least allow a setting for font type, size, and color.  This (expletive) is truly difficult to believe, given that this is 2015 and well over 20 yrs since MS touted their impeccable technology called IE.

Also, why the (expletive) do they not even allow a BG color for a field, so that a user can visuall the difference between computed fields and data-entry fields - the CRTs in the 1970s did that - yes, not kidding, they did.