# Change Font Color in Datasheet View

Tags: datasheet

I have a list that I have created in SharePoint 2010.  Some of my customers prefer working in “Datasheet View” only.  Can they change the font color to **red** in while in Datasheet View, or do they have to use Standard View?  Is there another application (CorasWorks) that we can use to be make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately you cannot re-format the datasheet view. Can't change the font to red.

Options available for customising the datasheet view are very limited.

See this [helpful thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23364/understanding-data-sheet-view-list-better-in-sharepoint-2010/23366#23366) and this [blog post](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2012/10/sharepoint-datasheet-faq/).

I'm not sure if this could be accomplished with 3rd party software.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Bamboo Data Viewer Web Part